# Developing new rich internet application

Tags: air, rich-internet-application

We are about to start developing a RWA(rich web application) for advanced data management on our web server using PHP/MYSQL/JavaScript. I just came across AIR, which as well as I can tell, allows you to run Flash applications on your desktop instead of in the browser. Do I have this right or am I way off base?

Are there any other options than AIR?

Data security is paramount. We need to be sure that any data stored locally can be encrypted and that the communications between the user and the server can be done so via SSL.

Speed to use is also very important, it can't lag like some flash apps.

Also we are web developers and our guys well versed with PHP/MYSQL/Javascript - can these languages be used with AIR or something similar or do we have to develop the full application in Flash?

This is more so a fact finding mission to see if the 'RIA' buzz can apply to our situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) & [WPF](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/) are some other options.  [Here's a page](http://www.migueljimenez.net/post/2008/07/22/UX-Choosing-Silverlight-vs-Flash-vs-WPF-vs-Air.aspx) that compares these with Flash & AIR.

Comment: Thank you, it appears that with our skill set AIR would be the best fit. Do you have any idea as to the security and speed of it?